# How to deal with such a situation with the situation when working with strings?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, string, preg-replace-callback

I create a web program that **corrects the word** if it is not correct. The program fix the incorrect word if it is **completely incorrect**. And if it is **partially incorrect**, then it can not be fixed. How to do so that he looked at **all possible options** for correcting words. Possible solutions I have. The solution is as follows: If the word is partially incorrect, then make it completely invalid and then fix it on the correct variant from the array. Usually, I am correcting those words in which the following letters exist in the upper and lower case: **"қ","ҷ","ӣ","ҳ","ӯ","ғ"**.

> Array with correct words from database:

```
$correct_words = array
(
1 => "муққаррар",
2 => "рӯғғноққҳо",
3 => "ӯҳдадорӣ",
4 => "озодӣ",
);
```

I **replace** the following characters in the **array** and **create a non-correct** version of the words and create a new **associative array** by passing an unconfigured version of the word to the array key and the correct variant to the value of the array.

> I replace the following letters in array with correct words:
>   **"қ","ҷ","ӣ","ҳ","ӯ","ғ"**
>
> To the following letters: **"к","ч","и","х","у","г"**

**The result is the following array:**

```
$dict = array
(
"муккаррар"  => "муққаррар",
"руггноккхо" => "рӯғғноққҳо",
"ухдадори"   => "ӯҳдадорӣ",
"озоди"      => "озодӣ"
)
```

> $text = "Рафтани ман ба донишгох **муққаррар** ба **рӯғғноққҳо** дар **ӯҳдадорӣ**
>   бо ерии **озодӣ**.";

How to do so if the user types the following words:

```
муққаррар
рӯғғноққҳо
ӯҳдадорӣ
озодӣ
```

In the following options

```
мукқаррар
муқкаррар

рӯғғноққҳо
руғғноққҳо
рӯгғноққҳо
рӯғгноққҳо
рӯғғнокқҳо
рӯғғноқкҳо
рӯғғноққхо
..........
etc combinations...
```

All kinds of compinations up, if from the side of the user is entered, then in any case they need to be corrected for the correct variant from the array.

Or advise to use **javascript** and correct the text, immediately upon typing with a hint of similar words in the array to the user

**Generally**, I can replace the following characters in the entered text: **"қ","ҷ","ӣ","ҳ","ӯ","ғ"**

To: **"к","ч","и","х","у","г"**

```
$text = "Рафтани ман ба донишгох муққаррар ба рӯғғноққҳо дар ӯҳдадорӣ бо ерии озодӣ.";

$search = array("қ","ҷ","ӣ","ҳ","ӯ","ғ");
$replace = array("к","ч","и","х","у","г");

$result = str_replace($search, $replace, $text);
```

> As a result, our text will be:

```
$text = "Рафтани ман ба донишгох муккаррар ба руггноккхо дар ухдадори бо ерии озоди.";
```

**And then I use this method to correct the text:**

```
$dict = array
(
"муккаррар"  => "муққаррар",
"руггноккхо" => "рӯғғноққҳо",
"ухдадори"   => "ӯҳдадорӣ",
"озоди"      => "озодӣ"
);

$result = preg_replace_callback("/\pL+/u", function ($m) use ($dict) {
    $word = mb_strtolower($m[0]);
    if (isset($dict[$word])) {
        $repl = $dict[$word];
        // Check for some common ways of upper/lower case
        // 1. all lower case
        if ($word === $m[0]) return $repl;
        // 2. all upper case
        if (mb_strtoupper($word) === $m[0]) return mb_strtoupper($repl);
        // 3. Only first letters are upper case
        if (mb_convert_case($word,  MB_CASE_TITLE) === $m[0]) return mb_convert_case($repl,  MB_CASE_TITLE);
        // Otherwise: check each character whether it should be upper or lower case
        for ($i = 0, $len = mb_strlen($word); $i < $len; ++$i) {
            $mixed[] = mb_substr($word, $i, 1) === mb_substr($m[0], $i, 1) 
                ? mb_substr($repl, $i, 1)
                : mb_strtoupper(mb_substr($repl, $i, 1));
        }
        return implode("", $mixed);
    }
    return $m[0]; // Nothing changes
}, $text);
```

**And in this case, to correct this text from the array will be possible.**
But if the user misses some letters in the word or writes some sort of letters in the correct version then problems appear.

> What should I do? How to manage in such mistakes?

Comment: Have you looked into [levenshtein()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php) or [similar_text()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php) ?

Comment: I have not yet looked at them. I'll see and try how to solve the problem. Thanks for the help.